# Ordenamiento en Query de Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, ordenamiento

tengo armada esta query en laravel y no me respeta el ordenamiento, sin embargo en SQL me funciona correctamente. estoy mostrando el resultado en un datatables.

```
 DB::select('SELECT t.id, DATE_FORMAT(t.dia, "%d/%m/%Y") dia, p.apellido,  concat(pa.apellido, "  ", pa.nombre) paciente, tr.descripcion tratamiento, t.hora,
        CASE t.tipo
        when "Turno" then "T"
        when "STurno" then "ST"
        when "STurnE" then "TE"
        else  "PR"
        END AS tipo 
       FROM turnos t
       LEFT JOIN profesionales p on  t.profesional=p.id
       LEFT JOIN pacientes pa on t.paciente=pa.id 
       LEFT JOIN tratamientos tr on t.tratamiento=tr.id
       Where DATE_FORMAT(t.dia, "%d/%m/%Y") >= DATE_FORMAT(now(), "%d/%m/%Y")
       order by t.profesional, t.anio, dia, t.hora asc');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cómo sabes que no respeta el ordenamiento?

Comment: me deberia mostrar todos los horarios de un dia de colacino y luego todos los horarios del mismo dia de Sanchez, como me aparece en el sql. Puede estar el problema en el datatables?

Comment: Lo que veo en la imagen es que el datatable tiene una flechita de ordenamiento en la primer columna. Para ver si la consulta devuelve los datos ordenado (o no), deberías hacer un dump del resultado. Por ej `$resultado = DB::select(...); Log::debug($resultado);` y revisa los logs para ver que te devuelve realmente.

Comment: Gracias por el dato., quizas fue error mio. mil gracias.-